# Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES"

Tags: php

I'm on the latest version of PHP. I have the following legacy code:

```
function send_message( $form_data ) {
    $name = filter_var( strip_tags( trim( $form_data['name'] ) ), FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES );
    $email = filter_var( $form_data['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL );
    $to = "John Doe <test@example.org>";
    $from = "$name <$email>";
    $reason = ucfirst( $form_data['reason'] );
    $subject = "Conact Form Filled out. Reason: $reason";
    $message = filter_var( strip_tags( trim( $form_data['message'] ) ), FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES );
    $message = 'From: ' . $from . ', for '. $reason . "\n\n" . $message;
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES"

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: It is gone: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecations_php_7_4 / And it was never the appropriate filter here. Unlikely that any MTA or client requires escaped quotes.

Answer (score 3):

This constant has been removed from the latest version of PHP. Check [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.constants.php#constant.filter-sanitize-magic-quotes) for more details. Use FILTER_SANITIZE_ADD_SLASHES instead.